# Webpack doesn't load images from css after build

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack

When I run npm run build `"build": "webpack"` webpack produces dist folder for me with `main.css`, `index.html` and `index.js` but the images from CSS or from HTML don't work and they are not there.

In CSS in dist folder they are referenced like so

```
background-image: url("../../../assets/img/works/works-3.jpg");
```

And in HTML

```
<img src="./assets/img/logo.png">
```

I'm not sure what to fix so my images are working.

I have this webpack config

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const SpritesmithPlugin = require('webpack-spritesmith');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: './src/app.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$|\.sass$|\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader?url=false'
                    },
                    { loader: 'sass-loader' }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            },
            {test: /\.png$|jpg|jpeg/, use: [
                'file-loader?name=i/[hash].[ext]'
            ]}
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.es6'],
        modules: ['node_modules', 'spritesmith-generated']
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        contentBase: './src',
        watchContentBase: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: '[name].css'
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html'
        }),
        new SpritesmithPlugin({
            src: {
                cwd: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/assets/img/icons'),
                glob: '*.png'
            },
            target: {
                image: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/spritesmith-generated/sprite.png'),
                css: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/spritesmith-generated/sprite.scss')
            },
            apiOptions: {
                cssImageRef: '../spritesmith-generated/sprite.png'
            }
        })
    ]
};
```

**UPD** installed `Copy Webpack Plugin` and copied assets folder to dist folder. Images in HTML are working fine, but images in CSS do not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using `CopyWebpackPlugin` you need to need to change your `background-url` to `/dist/images/imageName` . But it depends how are structuring your build folder. This plugin copy all assets to your build folder so you need to import them from your `dist` folder.

Comment: There must be a way to do it not manually right? Not just editing css in dist?

Comment: Hi an upvote would be highly appreciated. And since you need to do this manually when you are providing custom paths.  You can use editor replace all feature to update it once. Otherwise if you can share it over github I could solve it with file-loader too.